# What does "@" at the beginning of a command name mean?

Tags: macros, symbols

The [answers to this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/58506/how-to-make-a-new-command-similar-to-author/58512#58512) mention commands such as `\@author` and `\@director`, and latex.ltx is full of them. However, when I use `\@author` in my document, it just outputs the word "author". What does the `@` in command names mean?

Comment: See for example http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/106253/naming-conventions-for-macro-names-that-include-the-package-name, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/106174/makeatletter-explained, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8351/what-do-makeatletter-and-makeatother-do

Comment: `@` is a special character with special rules.  Joseph's pointers are an excellent place to start learning of it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `@` at the beginning of a command name is common way to implement a *private namespace,* that is, to define commands which are hidden from the user.  The user can therefore not inadvertantly modify them.  This is a safety belt.

The identifiant of a command—the text after the `\` character—must be a sequence of letters. TeX's idea of which character is a letter or not is defined by the table of *catcodes,* which can be reconfigured at run time.

Many packages find it useful to define *private* macros which cannot easily be accessed by the user, thus preventing the user to inadvertantly modify them or use them. This is achieved with catcodes in the following manner:

1. Arrange so that `@` has the catcode of a letter.
2. Define private macros, having the letter `@` in their names.
3. Arrange so that `@` has not the catcode of a letter anymore.

When user's code takes control of the flow of execution after step 3, it cannot inadvertantly interact with macros having a `@` in their name.

Comment: +1 Nice answer. "Preventing" is too strong a word, though. I'd write "reducing the risk that", instead. There is always a risk that a macro, internal or not, be overwritten. All it takes is one misplaced `\makeatletter`.

Comment: So a command such as `\@author` would only be used by other commands, rather than directly by the user? And when I use `\@author` in my document, it isn't evaluated as a command, but rather separately as `\@` and the text `author`? I only know [what `\@` does after characters such as punctuation or capital letters](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22561/what-is-the-proper-use-of-i-e-backslash-at).

Comment: @Jubobs If you play with makeatletter, you are not a user anymore but a developer! :-)

Comment: @Cerran You are perfectly right!

Comment: @user40989 The answer to Cerran's first question is "yes", but the answer to the second one is "no".

Comment: @Jubobs If `@` is not a letter, the typical case in a document, then `\@author` is actually split as `the command @` `the letter a` `the letter u` and so on.

Comment: @user40989 Do you have a reference for that?

Comment: @Jubobs It is probably adressed in the TeXbook, chapter “How TeX reads what you type” but I cannot check this out right now!