# What package(s) do I need to use to work \pgfdeclareshape and \pgf@xa, \pgf@xb, pgf@xc?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have been trying to use the following example from the TikZ and PGF Manual (ver. 3.1.3) pg. 1126, but when I do I get multiple errors. In particular, the compiler doesn't seem to recognize the names \pgf@xa, \pgf@xb, and \pgf@xc. It also states that the @ shouldn't come after \advance. I have tried various \usepackage{} statements but with no luck.And I am not clear if the \pgfdeclareshape should be within the scope of the document or before it.

```
\pgfdeclareshape{document}{
\inheritsavedanchors[from=rectangle] % this is nearly a rectangle
\inheritanchorborder[from=rectangle]
\inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{center}
\inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{north}
\inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{south}
\inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{west}
\inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{east}
% ... and possibly more
\backgroundpath{% this is new
% store lower right in xa/ya and upper right in xb/yb
\southwest \pgf@xa=\pgf@x \pgf@ya=\pgf@y
\northeast \pgf@xb=\pgf@x \pgf@yb=\pgf@y
% compute corner of ‘‘flipped page’’
\pgf@xc=\pgf@xb \advance\pgf@xc by-5pt % this should be a parameter
\pgf@yc=\pgf@yb \advance\pgf@yc by-5pt
% construct main path
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xa}{\pgf@ya}}
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xa}{\pgf@yb}}
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xc}{\pgf@yb}}
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xb}{\pgf@yc}}
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xb}{\pgf@ya}}
\pgfpathclose
% add little corner
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xc}{\pgf@yb}}
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xc}{\pgf@yc}}
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xb}{\pgf@yc}}
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xc}{\pgf@yc}}
}
}\hskip-1.2cm
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[shade,draw,shape=document,inner sep=2ex] (x) {Remark};
\node[fill=yellow!80!black,draw,ellipse,double]
at ([shift=(-80:3cm)]x) (y) {Use Case};
\draw[dashed] (x) -- (y);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Some more info about `\makeatletter`/`\makeatother`: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8351/ https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/164218

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to TeX-SE! In LaTeX `@` plays a special role, it is a nonstandard character unless you are in a package, or you use `\makeatletter`. This is to protect certain macros, dimensions etc. from accidentally being overwritten. So you may want to wrap the declaration of the shape in `\makeatletter ... \makeatother`, where the latter switches back to normal. In your example you also need `shapes.geometric` for the ellipse.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\pgfdeclareshape{document}{
\inheritsavedanchors[from=rectangle] % this is nearly a rectangle
\inheritanchorborder[from=rectangle]
\inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{center}
\inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{north}
\inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{south}
\inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{west}
\inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{east}
% ... and possibly more
\backgroundpath{% this is new
% store lower right in xa/ya and upper right in xb/yb
\southwest \pgf@xa=\pgf@x \pgf@ya=\pgf@y
\northeast \pgf@xb=\pgf@x \pgf@yb=\pgf@y
% compute corner of ''flipped page''
\pgf@xc=\pgf@xb \advance\pgf@xc by-5pt % this should be a parameter
\pgf@yc=\pgf@yb \advance\pgf@yc by-5pt
% construct main path
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xa}{\pgf@ya}}
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xa}{\pgf@yb}}
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xc}{\pgf@yb}}
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xb}{\pgf@yc}}
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xb}{\pgf@ya}}
\pgfpathclose
% add little corner
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xc}{\pgf@yb}}
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xc}{\pgf@yc}}
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xb}{\pgf@yc}}
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xc}{\pgf@yc}}
}
}
\makeatother
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[shade,draw,shape=document,inner sep=2ex] (x) {Remark};
\node[fill=yellow!80!black,draw,ellipse,double]
at ([shift=(-80:3cm)]x) (y) {Use Case};
\draw[dashed] (x) -- (y);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]