# What is the difference between control sequences begining with `\` and the ones begining with `\@`?

Tags: macros, tex-core, latex3

In all LaTeX packages documentations that show their internal codes, we see `\@` and often we see `\@@` or even `\@@@`. What is the difference between `\` and `\@`? What does it mean to write more `@` to start a control sequence or instruction?

Comment: For example https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8351/what-do-makeatletter-and-makeatother-do, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/106253/naming-conventions-for-macro-names-that-include-the-package-name, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/106174/makeatletter-explained: the `@` is used as an extra 'letter' for internal macro names, beyond that there is not much pattern (except `\@@<name>` is used by the kernel to save primitives).

Comment: Or some more answers at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11078/what-is-the-difference-between-myname-and-myname-while-writing-a-cls-file